# How to send callback message from nested custom view to controller elegantly?

Tags: ios, objective-c

**For example:**

There is a `controller` with a `redCustomView` in which is a `greenCustomView` in which is a `buleCustomView` with a `button`.

**Question:**

How to send callback message to `controller` when `button` clicked?

**My solutions:**

1. Using `blcok to block` send callback message view by view;
2. Using `delegate to delegate` send callback message view by view;
3. Using `notification` send callback message from `view` to `controller` directly.

**Problem:**

Using `block` or `delegate` appears so massive;

Using `notification`? Everybody could receive this notification message,so I don't think it's a better way.

**Wonder:**

Is there any other better way to solve this problem elegantly?

Comment: yes, you are right. Notification is not a good way to do this.
Block or Delegate are good options but you need to maintain there references.
Explain your flow to help me understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Block is comparatively easy to implement, One way to achieve this is simple pass block from A to B and then B to C and in C call it.

Comment: What will be the outcome when you click on button?

Comment: Is just adding an action either via IB or programmatically (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the long run, you need to make your *base architecture* concise and testable. I would thus suggest using [**MVVM**](https://www.toptal.com/ios/swift-tutorial-introduction-to-mvvm) approach and use the concept of **binding** for doing whatever you want to do via viewController's callback function. Using this, your view model is bonded to your view and code would be *automatically* called on button click.
As you'll start to discover this, you'll concurrently see that your *massive viewController* slowly and slowly changes to a concise and neat class. If you are not much aware of [**MVVM binding**](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/how-to-use-a-model-view-viewmodel-architecture-for-ios-46963c67be1b), it would appear like Chinese to you. But trust me, once you get habitual, you won't hesitate to use that along.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is walk up the responder chain until I come to the view controller. This is trivially easy in your use case — a button tap — because all you have to do is give the button a *nil-targeted action* and the runtime will find the handler implementation in the view controller for you.

Comment: If you don’t know what a nil-targeted action is or how to make one, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_nil_targeted_actions

Comment: Thanks a lot.But,what if there are several paraments in controller's method?How can I send several value to controller when I clicked the button?

Comment: Then your architecture is wrong. A button should not “know” several values. That’s not what a button is, or does. It’s message is that it was tapped, that’s all.

Answer (score 0):

To find the elegant solution, one needs only to look at Apple's own views.   UITableView, for example has a delegate that must adopt the UITableViewDelegate protocol.   The delegate is notified of user interactions by the view, e.g., tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:.   So, the "elegant solution" in this case is protocol/delegate.   However, if you're building your view hierarchy in viewDidLoad as opposed to building a true custom view that is a subclass of, say, UIControl, then the target-action method is a common solution.